# Case Insensitivy in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a users sign up form, but when the users sign back in they are required to type their email address with the same cases as they signed up with. I have measures to prevent this, but for some strange reason they are not working.

In the users model:

```
validates :email, :presence => true,
                  :format   => { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

This was not working... im not sure why. but then I added another method to see what it did:

```
before_save :downcase_fields
def downcase_fields
 self.email.downcase 
end
```

and down cased the fields when users type them in with this in my sessions controller:

```
def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email].downcase,
                          params[:session][:password])
    #...
end
```

All of this still yields a case sensitive email field when the users sign back in... help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.email.downcase!
```

Comment: oops, i did forget the "!". thanks! but any idea why the first part wasnt doing its job? im curious

Comment: My reading of it is that it checks that there's no other record in the database with the same email of any case, but does not allow you to find the email unless it's the same case.